# If g is a PRG and f is a OWF, is G'(x) = f(g(x)) a PRG?

Tags: complexity-theory, pseudo-random-generators, mathematical-analysis, one-way-functions

Just like the title states.

If I have a pseudo-random generator $g\colon \Sigma^n \rightarrow \Sigma^{2n}$ and a one-way function $f$, is $g'(x)=f(g(x))$ a pseudo-random generator? And why?

My instinct tells me it is, but I can't really explain why.

Comment: Try using the definitions.

Comment: "A Pseudorandom generator (PRG) is an efficient and deterministic function, which returns a longer pseudorandom output sequence based on the received shorter input:
$G:{0,1}^s \rightarrow {0,1}^n$, where $n >> s$."
"A one-way function is a function that is easy to compute on every input, but hard to invert given the image of a random input."

Does it have to do with the fact that $f$ is not guaranteed to "strech" the input string?

Comment: These are not formal definitions. Try using the formal definitions.

Comment: I'm looking at the [wikipedia formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_generator#Definition) (my professor's slides are really lacking) and I can't seem to figure it out. Is it because it is possible that $f$ won't "cheat" a distinguisher, since the statistical distance between the distributions $A(G(U_{\ell }))$ and $A(U_{n})$ can be become greater than $\epsilon$?

Comment: Have you seen any proofs using these definitions?

Comment: I don't think I have. With the virus stuff and all, my classes were kinda hurt since we didn't do any exercises in web classes, so I'm really lacking in that department.

Comment: If you have never seen an example of a crypto proof, there’s no way you will be able to come up with one.

Comment: Check out Goldreich's foundations of cryptography or introduction to modern cryptography. Many books cover the basics of PRGs and one-way functions, there you will find the proofs you seek.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Forget about the stretch of the PRG and let's instead focus on the whether the output of $f$ necessarily looks like a random string (even if we give it a truly random string instead of a PRG output).

**Answer:** The claim is false for a general OWF.
A OWF is not guaranteed to have a "random looking" output. Specifically, the output can have an obvious tell which distinguishes it from a truly random string, e.g., $f(x)$ may always start with the bit $0$. In this case, a simple distinguisher that outputs the first bit of the given string has a constant advantage, which means that $f(x)$ is not pseudorandom. Extending this to show that $f(g(x))$ is not a PRG should be straightforward.